# how many string objects are being created in new String(" ");

Tags: java, string

having this code block:

```
String x = new String("xyz");
String y = "abc";
x = x + y;
```

how many string objects are being created on the JVM?

Comment: Look at all those related questions.

Comment: 2 literals + 1 via `new` + 1 via `+`

Comment: `String` costructor actually calls the `StringBuffer` constructor.